Strange behavior when passing a cable captures `std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Conversation>>` to the complete handler
The code snippet below always closes the connection at once when a client has connected to the server, which is really out of my expectation.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <system_error>
#include "tcp_server.hpp"


TcpServer::TcpServer(asio::io_context& io_context,
      const unsigned int& port):m_acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
{
  do_accept();
}

void TcpServer::do_accept()
{
      m_acceptor.async_accept(make_strand(m_acceptor.get_executor()),
      [this](const std::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
      {
            if (!error)
            {
              std::make_shared<Conversation>(std::move(socket))->do_start();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "Error accepting connection: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }

            // Start accepting the next connection
            do_accept();
      });
}

Conversation::Conversation(tcp::socket socket) : m_socket(std::move(socket))
{ 
  std::cout << "creating conversation:" << this << std::endl;
}

void Conversation::do_read()
{
    std::cout << "do read" << std::endl;
    auto conversation_ptr{shared_from_this()};
     m_socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(m_data),
        [this, conversation_ptr](std::error_code error, size_t length) {
          if (!error)
          {
              do_write(std::string("reply:") + std::string{m_data.data(), length});
              do_read();
              std::cout << "data read: " << m_data.data() << std::endl;
          }
          else
          {
              std::cout << "error in reading data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
          }
        });
}

void Conversation::do_start()
{
  do_read();
}

void Conversation::do_write(std::string str)
{
  auto conversation_ptr{shared_from_this()};
  m_socket.async_send(asio::buffer(str), [this, conversation_ptr](std::error_code error, size_t length ){
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "data write successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error in writing data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  });
}

Conversation::~Conversation()
{
   std::cout << "destroying conversation:" << this << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  asio::io_context io_context;
  TcpServer server{io_context, 12345};

  io_context.run();
}

Since auto conversation_ptr{shared_from_this()}; constructs an instance of std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Conversation>> and the complete handler captures the conversation_ptr, I think the instance of Conversation would be kept alive when the complete handler is invoked if some message is sent from the client. However, the output of the server always something like this, below.
./tcp_server 
creating conversation:0x1cad8d0
do read
destroying conversation:0x1cad8d0
error in reading data: Operation aborted.

^C

At the mean time, here is the output of telnet below, which indicates the server other than the client closes the connection.
telnet 0.0.0.0 12345
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.0.0.0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

What's more, it works well if the auto conversation_ptr{shared_from_this()}; is replaced by auto conversation_ptr(shared_from_this());. What a surprise!
The used compiler is clang++ 3.4.
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

The used asio library is V1.29.0.
#define ASIO_VERSION 102900 // 1.29.0

The platform is Ubuntu 14.04.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty


Note: As per this post, the definition of max_align_t has been added to make the code snippet compile with clang++ 3.4.

A more complete [mcve] would be a good improvement to this post. You're asking us to take a lot of assumptions about the definition of Conversation on trust.

Incidentally, from a high level, in my opinion this sort of juggling of savior-references in functors to keep things alive is a poor design. The setup and teardown of a Conversation has side effects; it deserves an explicit and intentional lifetime, not an emergent one.

@Sneftel  1. Because the strange behaviour is observed with the aforementioned code snippet, I can't reproduce it with a smaller code now. 2. savior-references in functors to keep things alive is a poor design. We can't know when the connection is closed or encountered some error in advance.

@John He was not asking for a smaller code but for a more complete code :)

@Fareanor  Thank you for the explaination. Sorry for my poor English. The code in SO is complete since it can reproduce the problem while no extra information or code is needed. If I am wrong, please let me know.

std::initializer_list holds a reference to a temporary array. This is lifetime extended like a normal const reference, i.e., the temporary ends its lifetime when the original initializer_list ends its lifetime.
So, the captured copy initializer_list becomes dangling once the lambda is called: the shared_ptr it was referring to has already been destroyed. The reason auto conversation_ptr(shared_from_this()); works is that you capture a shared_ptr directly and the lambda holds a copy.

Also auto conversation_ptr{shared_from_this()}; only makes a std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Conversation>> before N3922. Afterwards, it becomes a std::shared_ptr<Conversation>. Starting from Clang 3.6, you started getting this warning:

warning: direct list initialization of a variable with a deduced type will change meaning in a future version of Clang; insert an '=' to avoid a change in behavior [-Wfuture-compat]


And was finally implemented in Clang 3.8, so I suspect this code was written for a newer compiler

std::initializer_list holds a reference to a temporary array? I can't find such similar statement here and there.

@John https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#List-initializing_std::initializer_list (Also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list says it's a proxy object, i.e. just a pointer to something else)

Thank you for the detailed explaination. Yeap, it says Each element of the backing array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer to that array.. Therefore, std::initializer_list<E> is a reference to the array other than refrerences to each elment of the arrary.  For example, auto nums={1,2,3}; constructing a std::initializer_list<int> named nums which references to the baking array other than the elements. Am I right? If I am wrong, please let me know.

And was finally implemented in Clang 3.8, so I suspect this code was written for a newer compiler. Sorry, I can't understand what you mean by the text in bold.

@John I don't quite understand what you mean (the backing array is the elements). Another way of saying it is with std::inititalizer_list<int> nums = {1, 2, 3};, it's like const int __temp[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; std::inititalizer_list<int> nums /* nums.data() == __temp; nums.size() == 3 */;

@John On a newer compiler, auto variable{ E } isn't an initializer_list, but the same type as E, so you wouldn't have this problem

Thanks to Artyer.
For the readers who read this post later, how the different versions of compilers work with the same code snippet would help to fully understand it.
